How do I find which element has focus in Accessibility mode in Android Compose?
I need to do some stuff when the composable has a focus in accessibility mode but i cannot seem to find a way to do it.
I cannot capture the moment when the focus is on the composable in accessibility mode.
I tried the following code, but no luck:
          Text(
            text = "message",
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(FocusRequester())
                .focusable()
                .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                    if (focusState.isFocused) {
                        // do stuff
                    }
                }
          )


The problem with the code is the order of modifiers; You should have the focusable as the last item. You can read more from the documentation's Precedence of focus modifiers-section. So the working code would be:
    Text(
      text = "message",
      modifier = Modifier
         .focusRequester(FocusRequester())
         .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
           if (focusState.isFocused) {
             // do stuff
           }
         }
         .focusable()
    )

